# Line Height with the built in OSX Font Panel

Tags: macos

I am using an invoiving application, and would like to adjust some text properties including line height, but the only options available are show in the attached screenshot.  Does anyone have an idea how to adjust line height when the only tool you have is this font-chooser thingy (Is there a name for this)?

[image: OSX Lineheight]

Thank you.

Comment: This is your font library, called font-book, you define your font properties in the relevant programme.

Comment: In which application do you want to use the font?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The panel you're referring to is called the Font Panel. Unfortunately, there is no option to change the line height in it.

You can read more about technicalities of the panel [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSFontPanel_Class/Reference/Reference.html), although the documentation is hard to read.

It's likely that the developer of the application you are using is just using the stock panel (there aren't any options provided with it). It's kind of difficult and not really worth it to add new functionality to that panel, from my experience as a developer. It's better to just start from scratch than to use it.

Comment: Thanks for your answers guys. Yes it's not font-book. I'm using a invoicing app which has only this "Font Panel" for styling the invoices.

Well sad to hear line height adjustments aren't included.

Comment: Yes, it seems rudimentary, I suppose it's a developer choice though to not implement such features, and doesn't reflect on OSX as such - the Font panel is just that, a font picker, not a layout or design tool, and as such is lacks all the other relevant layout options like justification, wrap, kerning, etc etc.

Comment: I think the Terminal one is the only font picker in the OS that lets you choose line height.

Answer (score 4):

This is Fontbook. It is simply a font library, not where you manipulate fonts. You do not define font properties there:

> The Font Book application lets you install, remove, view, organize,
>   validate, enable, and disable fonts. Fonts are styles of type that
>   your computer uses to display and print text. OS X comes with many
>   preinstalled fonts.

The programme you are using will (or will not) have the tools to format fonts. If your programme does not have this, you cannot set this in Fontbook.

Comment: But it is not Fontbook, it's the Font Panel you get by doing Format > Font > Show Fonts.  The last sentence of course correct.